# R - Multiple compasses in tmap

Tags: r, tmap

Is it possible to include more than one `tm_compass()` on a map created by `tmap`?

I know it's probably unlikely that you'd need to, but say you wanted to show off the different compass types. Using `nz` from the `spData` package I tried adding each new compass as an additional layer, but it seems only the first one is included on the map.

```
library(spData)
library(tmap)

tm_shape(nz)+
  tm_fill()+
  tm_compass(type = 'arrow', position = c(0.1, 0.9))+
  tm_compass(type = '4star', position = c(0.1, 0.8))+
  tm_compass(type = '8star', position = c(0.1, 0.7))+
  tm_compass(type = 'radar', position = c(0.1, 0.6))+
  tm_compass(type = 'rose', position = c(0.1, 0.5))
```

[image]

If `arrow` isn't included, then `4star` takes it's place:

```
tm_shape(nz)+
  tm_fill()+
  # tm_compass(type = 'arrow', position = c(0.1, 0.9))+
  tm_compass(type = '4star', position = c(0.1, 0.8))+
  tm_compass(type = '8star', position = c(0.1, 0.7))+
  tm_compass(type = 'radar', position = c(0.1, 0.6))+
  tm_compass(type = 'rose', position = c(0.1, 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: I don't think it is possible. For demonstration purposes, you can simply arrange different maps with different compasses with `tmap_arrange`

Comment: Thanks Elia, `tmap_arrange()` is looking like the best option

Comment: Nice question, I have been exploring some work around methods and it does not seem to be a straightforward way. Recommendation by Elia is probably the best way.

Comment: Hi @hugh-allan, please find below one possible solution to your request... hoping that it will still be useful for you! Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interesting question. As you point out, in normal use it is unlikely that one would need to display multiple compasses for the same map and that is probably why the default behavior of the `tmap` library does not handle this case.

That said, it is still possible to add all five `tmap` compasses to the same map using some workarounds! So, please find below the general "strategy":

1. Building 5 maps, each with one of the `tmap` compasses. Then convert these maps into 'grob' objects using the `tmap::tmap_grob()` function to extract the compasses with the help of the `getGrob()` function from the `base R` library `grid`.
2. Visualizing the compasses (without and with labels) using the `cowplot` library
3. Building the final map with the five compasses using the `cowplot` library

*NB: when running the reprex just below, don't worry about the rendering of the different plots that will be displayed in your `plotting device` (as the rendering depends on the aspect ratio of the device); what matters is the rendering of the maps saved in the `.png` files.*

### **Reprex**

**STEP 1 - EXTRACT EACH COMPASS TYPE FROM FIVE 'DUMMY' MAPS AS 'GROB' OBJECTS**

```r
library(tmap)
library(spData)
library(grid)

# Get a list named 'maps' containing 5 maps, each one with a different compass
compass_type <- c("arrow", "4star", "8star", "radar", "rose")

maps <- lapply(compass_type,
               function(x)
                 tm_shape(nz) +
                 tm_fill() +
                 tm_compass(type = x, position = c(0.1, 0.7)))


# Get a list named 'compasses' containing the 5 compasses as 'grob' objects 
compasses <- lapply(maps, function(x) getGrob(tmap_grob(x), gPath("compass")))
```

**STEP 2 - VISUALIZATION OF THE FIVE `tmap` COMPASSES**

- *Without labels*

```r
library(cowplot)

compasses_only <- plot_grid(plotlist = compasses,
                            nrow = 3,
                            ncol = 2,
                            scale = 0.8, 
                            byrow = TRUE)

compasses_only

# Save the plot (need to install the 'rstudioapi' library)
# NB: adjust 'width' and 'height' params to get the best possible rendering 
rstudioapi::savePlotAsImage(
  "tmap_compasses.png", # add the path if different of the working directory   
  format = "png", # other possible formats: "jpeg", "bmp", "tiff", "emf", "svg", "eps"
  width = 780,
  height = 965
)
```

[image]

- *With labels*

```r
compasses_only_labeled <- plot_grid(plotlist = compasses,
                            nrow = 3,
                            ncol = 2,
                            scale = 0.8, 
                            labels = compass_type,
                            label_size = 10,
                            label_x = c(0.42, 0.43, 0.43, 0.42, 0.44),
                            label_y = 0.1,
                            byrow = TRUE)

compasses_only_labeled

# Save the plot (need to install the 'rstudioapi' library)
# NB: adjust 'width' and 'height' params to get the best possible rendering 
rstudioapi::savePlotAsImage(
  "tmap_compasses_labeled.png",  
  format = "png", 
  width = 780,
  height = 965
)
```

[image]

**STEP 3 - BUILDING THE MAP WITH THE FIVE COMPASSES**

```r
# Get a 'nz' map (without any compass) as 'grob' object 
nz_map <- tmap_grob(tm_shape(nz) + tm_fill())

# Convert 'compasses_only" into 'grob' object
compasses_only <- cowplot::as_grob(compasses_only)

# Build the map with the 5 compasses
map_with_compasses_2 <- ggdraw() +
  draw_grob(nz_map) +
  draw_grob(compasses_only,
            width = 0.23, height = 0.65,
            x = 0.28, y = 0.35,
            hjust = 0,
            vjust = 0,
            halign = 0.5,
            valign = 0.5,
            scale = 0.8)

map_with_compasses_2

# Save the plot (need to install the 'rstudioapi' library)
# NB: adjust 'width' and 'height' params to get the best possible rendering 
rstudioapi::savePlotAsImage(
  "map_with_compasses_2.png",   
  format = "png", 
  width = 1500,
  height = 900
)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-01-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your effort here @lovalery, impressive answer :)

Comment: @hugh-allan, thank you very much for your feedback and your kind words. Cheers.